# Ruby: Bundler doesn't like VERSION not being a hard-coded constant

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I use the `versionomy` gem to manage the internal versioning of my gems.  That means that my `lib/<gem>/version.rb` file tents to contain something like this:

```
@version  = Versionomy.parse('0.0.1')
#
# explain what happened to cause the bump
#
@version.bump(:minor)
@version.freeze
VERSION   = @version.to_s
```

However, `bundler` *really* doesn't like having the `versionomy` gem be a pre-requisite of bundler's own work.  It gives different complaints depending upon how I try to work around it.

Is there a trick to registering/requiring a gem so `bundle check` (at its simplest) will complain but continue?  The `versionomy` gem is in my system gem repo, so it's not like it's completely unknown or inaccessible.

Thanks!

Comment: “It gives different complaints”—what exactly does `bundler` complain about?

Comment: It'll take me a bit to try to recreate them all, but `Bundler can't satisfy your Gemfile's dependencies.` is one of them.

Comment: Hmm.  It must have gotten fixed in some more recent version of Bundler than I've been using.  "Never mind."  and Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unable to reproduce the problem using `bundler 1.16.1`.  Assume it's been fixed.  Thanks!